# header with lowercase letters

Tags: fancyhdr

I want to write a document with oneside style in which the chapter titles and the section titles in header appear with lowercase letters.

I use this code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\fancypagestyle{my}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter~:\ ##1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~\ ##1}}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\textit{\leftmark}}{\textit{\rightmark}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{my}
    \chapter{Chapter One}
    \section{Section One}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: do you want that “Section One” becomes “section one“ in the header?

Comment: No, i have : 1.1 SECTION ONE . I want 1.1 Section One

Comment: I can’t reproduce the whole uppercase with the code in the question

Comment: OK, now you say you want `Section One`. First you said you wanted lowercase, and in my book that means `section one`. With the example you gave above here, I already get `Section One`, not `SECTION ONE`.

Comment: The question is not answerable as it stands. If I run the code, I don't get headers in all uppercase (except possibly for the front matter parts such as the table of contents, because for them uppercase is hardwired in the class). Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\fancyhead[R]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\textit{\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}}{\textit{\MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}}}
```

This also makes the word `chapter` in the header lowercase. If you don't want that, then put the `\MakeLowercase` on the `##1` in `\chaptermark` instead:

```
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter~:\ \MakeLowercase{##1}}{}}
...
    \fancyhead[R]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\textit{\leftmark}}{\textit{\MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}}}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I have always 1.1 SECTION ONE.

Comment: Then you must have another document than the one given in your question. And in that case you may try to use `\nouppercase{\leftmark}` and `\nouppercase{\rightmark}`.

Comment: Thank you Pieter van Oostrum,  with \nouppercase it work perfectly.